# Text gets cut off

Tags: php

I have this PHP code:

```
<?php
    include 'imagem.php';

    $imagem = new Image(502, 500, '#1C3C41');
    $imagem->setFont('Verdana', 14, '#fade45');

    $mapcrew = json_decode(utf8_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.formice.com/mapcrew/online.json")));
    foreach($mapcrew as $server=>$list) {
        $line = new Line();
        $line->marginTop = 2;
        $line->addText(strtoupper($server) . ':', 'Verdana Bold', 12, '#009D9D');
        $line->addLineBreak();
        $line->addText(implode(', ', array_unique($list)), 'Verdana', 12, '#6C77C1', 4);
        $imagem->drawLine($line);
    }

    $imagem->flushImg();
?>
```

The problem is the text getting cut off because the image is too small. Is there any way to make a characters limit per limit or putting a LineBreak after the text gets cut off? I don't know how to fix it without changing the size of the image.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GD function imagettfbbox. You need to load a ttf font for this.

```
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php
```

Check example here.

[Calculating Text Width with PHP GD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696920/calculating-text-width-with-php-gd)