# Getting the length of the text given the height in php

Tags: php, html, css

Writing text to an input in html. Then it is given a dimension. For example, given 10, a calculation will be made so that each letter is 10 cm high and the length of the sentence will be found. How can I do that. I give the text in the input a size of px. Then I convert it to cm, but how can I calculate the length of the sentence in cm? I need to use php as language.

Comment: This depends directly on the font you are using. Perhaps you could use `imagettftext()` to write some text and then read the returned bounding box to calculate the ratio between height and width. This could then be used with your *height* input to calculate the width.
If not, you could directly do that with some JavaScript inside the HTML page itself, without posting the data to the server for PHP calculation. But the font on the client side might differ a bit, depending on the font in the CSS, the browser and the OS.

Comment: I couldn't do it with this library. Do you have any other suggestions

Comment: Did you have a look at this answer/solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696920/calculating-text-width-with-php-gd